# Как сохранять содержимое WebView внутри фрагмента?

Tags: java, android, webview

есть несколько фрагментов(играют роль вкладок), внутри каждого WebView.
При переключении на другую вкладку(фрагментов) предыдущая сбрасывается и грузит стартовую страницу.
подскажите как сделать, что бы при переключении WebView сохранялось состояние страницы до полного закрытия приложения?

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    public static WebView mWebView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webViewT1);
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Maps/web/map.html");
        }
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                        && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && mWebView.canGoBack())
                {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
        WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();

        // Clear all the cookies
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();

        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.clearFormData();
        mWebView.clearHistory();
        mWebView.clearSslPreferences();

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return v;
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }


    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                    return tab3;
                case 3:
                    Tab4 tab4 = new Tab4();
                    return tab4;
                case 4:
                    Tab5 tab5 = new Tab5();
                    return tab5;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "вкладка 1";
                case 1:
                    return "вкладка 2";
                case 2:
                    return "вкладка 3";
                case 3:
                    return "вкладка 4";
                case 4:
                    return "вкладка 5";
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: По идее простым способом это сделать будет использовать add вместо replace при смене фрагментов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил проблему:
offscreenPageLimit у ViewPager по умолчанию 1

то есть нужно его увеличить до нужного кол-ва фрагментов(вкладок)

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```